# Woocommerce add field data to Order_ID

Tags: woocommerce

Currently using the following code to configure how my Woocommerce order_ID displays. I want to add a number that the user has defined in the order_comments field of the payment page after the suffix below. I have tired a few different codes but nothing seems to work. Is this even possible ?

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_product_to_cart' );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
   $prefix = '#';
   $suffix = ' - File: ';

    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id . $suffix ;
    return $new_order_id;
}
```

Fairly new to coding.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved It .. Thanks Anyway

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_product_to_cart' );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
   $prefix = '#';
   $suffix = ' - File: ';
   $value = get_field( "order_comments" );
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id . $suffix ;
    return $new_order_id;
}
```